# Wrapping with application.html - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wrapper

I am really new to rails and working to customize a project. I generated a new scaffold, called it `New_Scaffold`. When the New_Scaffold's index.html.erb is displayed, the wrapper of the application.html.erb (where the `yield` method is called) is not displayed.

I thought it was automatic in rails, is it not ? How can I display the application.html.erb to wrap the New_Scaffold's index.html ?

Answer (score 0):

the application.html.erb file can be found under views/layouts

Comment: Yes, there is in views/layout  the application.html.erb file

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: sorry, pretty new here, will do.  user1611830 that's where the file resides so if it's there, that's the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The `scaffold` command generates a bunch of things for a model and controller for you automatically.

If you want to try Rails out try to create a new project like this:

```
rails new blog

cd blog

rails generate scaffold Post title body:text

rake db:migrate

rails server
```

This will create a basic project with one model, `Post`, that will have a generic setup with views and a controller that responds to all the RESTful actions.

Comment: That's exactly what I did : New_Scaffold controller inherits from the Application Controller which uses as a defalut layout application. But  the application/html.erb doesn't display...